# Skip resource creation if an argument in a map is not provided

Tags: azure, foreach, terraform, azure-rm

I'm using terraform v.0.13 to create some infrastructure in Azure. I'm using a variable to define a map of subnets, like shown below:

```
subnets = {
  "subnet1" = {
    address_prefixes       = ["example"]
    network_security_group = "example"
    route_table            = "example"
  },
  "subnet2" = {
    address_prefixes       = ["example2"]
    network_security_group = "example2"
    route_table            = "example2"
   },
}
```

Based on that, I create a a network security group and route table association with the "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" and "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" resources, based on `for_each = var.subnets`. Everything is fine if the subnet map have both the `network_security_group` and `route_table` arguments set, but if one of them or both are missing, the terraform plan fails with an error. I would like to skip the creation of the association resources if `network_security_group` and/or `route_table` arguments are not defined, any idea how I can archive that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe it would be better to make `network_security_group` and `route_table` compulsory?

Comment: It was an option which I was considering, but I would prefer to be more elastic in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found out a solution:

A the resource network security group association level, added the following conditional:

```
{ for name, subnet in var.subnets : name => subnet if lookup(subnet, "network_security_group", "") != "" }
```

Similar thing with "route_table" - tested, works just fine.